# sql server service broker queue pass parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

**Stored Procedure**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitServiceLog] 
(
@name varchar(max)=null
)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    insert into [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[ServiceBroker_Log](Service) values(@name)
END
```

**Service Broker Queue calling Stored Procedure Name "InitServiceLog"**

```
CREATE QUEUE dbo.SSBSLearningInitiatorQueue
WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF ,
ACTIVATION
(
STATUS = ON ,
PROCEDURE_NAME =[dbo].[InitServiceLog], 

///// is there any way to pass Stored                                        
///// Procedures Parameters from here
///// Like this "PROCEDURE_NAME =[dbo].[InitServiceLog]('log')

MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 10,
EXECUTE AS OWNER
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In above query Queue how to call stored procedure

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions - this was also posted on Stack Overflow -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601982/sql-server-service-broker-queue-pass-parameter-to-stored-procedure. If you feel that this is a better fit for DBA.SE, then flag your question for the moderators to move it or delete it from Stack Overflow before posting it on another site.

Comment: @vivek Please delete [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601982/sql-server-service-broker-queue-pass-parameter-to-stored-procedure).

Comment: deleted from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601982

Answer (score 4):

No, activation stored procedures are called "in a vacuum" so they don't allow passing parameters (there's "nothing" calling it) nor is there even a user context in which to execute, which is why the `EXECUTE AS` syntax exists and is required for activation.

If you need to abstract the logic, it can be separated into two procedures. The activation procedure is parameterless, but it can call another with parameters. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CentralizedLogic]
(
    @p1 varchar(MAX) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[QueueActivator]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[CentralizedLogic] @p1 = 'blah';
END


CREATE QUEUE [dbo].[MyQueue]
    WITH
        ...
        ACTIVATION
        (
            ...
            PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[QueueActivator]
            ...
        );
```